# GenericNackResponseException

Tags: java, smpp, jsmpp

I create SMPP Server Simulatorn with JSMPP. It is OK when accepting the message, but when I want to send delivery report or message I get this exception.

```
InvalidResponseException
org.jsmpp.GenericNackResponseException: Receive generic_nack with command_status 00000003
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.AbstractGenericSMPPSessionBound.processGenericNack(AbstractGenericSMPPSessionBound.java:97)
        at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessServerTask.run(PDUProcessServerTask.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I send message I set registered Delivery 0, but when I set it 0xf I dont get this exception, but the receiver didn't accept any message

Answer (score 2):

**GENERIC_NACK** response may be sent by many reasons.

However this part of output may help:

> Receive generic_nack with **command_status 00000003**

In part 5.1.3 of SMPP v3.4 specification this mentioned as **ESME_RINVCMDID (Invalid Command ID)**. So probably you have sent SMPP PDU with incorrect command_id (or unsupported by system you connect to).

Probably it's reasonable to provide part of your code throwing exceptions and testing process description.

Comment: Reason is that, I send delivery report, but receiver didn't connect to our server as Transceiver. For this reason I got this exception. Thanks for attention ))

Answer (score 0):

You can take tcpdump and investigate this issue in the  WireShark.

Or post you dump here. We can investigate it.

On linux you can use this command in the console to take dump:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -nnvvS -s 65535 -w smpp.cap host your_host_name
```

Very useful info about analize smpp issues 
It saved me many hours of debugging my code

[article about using tcpdump to analize smpp issues](http://support.omobio.net/redmine/projects/general-public/wiki/How_to_analyze_message_transactions_with_tcpdump)